# Js error on shopping cart on magento 2.4.2-p1

Tags: javascript, cart, error, magento2.4

I have this issue on a 2.2.11 Magento migrated to 2.4.2-p1 :
To reproduce it I just have to :
-Place product(s) on shopping cart
-Go to shopping cart
-Insert location for shipping click "order"
then I get this error :

"main.js:3 TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined"

and I am redirected to "empty cart page"
Any clues ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to sort this out. This was due to a change in order email template. disabling order email solved it, and I changed order email content in order to make it work.